# tableview header in two rows

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, header, uilabel

i'm italian, so sorry for my "ugly" english!

I'm working with a UITableview and my (dynamic) headers are too long!
So i want to split the headers in two rows... is it possible?

i've tried to uso "label.numberOfLines = 2" (or = 0) but it doesn't works!

this is the code:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSString *header1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Between %@ and %@ \n (33ª and 37ª week)", dateString1, dateString2];

    if (section == 0){
            label.text = header1;
            label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 6, 300, 30);
    } else
    //the others header

    label.numberOfLines = 2;

    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    [view autorelease];
    [view addSubview:label];

    return view;}
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

label.numberOfLines = 2 will only show if the height of the label is enough to accommodate two lines. Also, the line height will depend on the font size. Make sure label is heigh enough to fit two lines of text at the given font size. Try making the font smaller or the label bigger.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the frame for your label even on the else, specially because it needs to be bigger to accommodate the two lines of text.

You could do something like this:

```
    label.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30); // trying bigger heights
    label.numberOfLines = 2;
    // ...
```